# Playscape Publishing Kit failing with Error unknown during apply patch process

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, playscape

Running `Unity 4.5.4f1` and `Playscape SDK version 1.14`, building for android target, I am getting an **Error unknown** during the apply patch process in Unity. When running the executed command in CMD, I get the following error:

> **Error: Could not find or load main class com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2jarCmd**

The command input I provide (taken from the SDK logger) is the following:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51/bin/java.exe" -clas
spath Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/ThirdParty/dex2jar\lib/asm-all-3.3.1.jar;A
ssets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/ThirdParty/dex2jar\lib/commons-lite-1.15.jar;Asse
ts/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/ThirdParty/dex2jar\lib/dex-ir-1.12.jar;Assets/Plugin
s/Playscape/Editor/ThirdParty/dex2jar\lib/dex-reader-1.15.jar;Assets/Plugins/Pla
yscape/Editor/ThirdParty/dex2jar\lib/dex-tools-0.0.9.15.jar;Assets/Plugins/Plays
cape/Editor/ThirdParty/dex2jar\lib/dex-translator-0.0.9.15.jar;Assets/Plugins/Pl
ayscape/Editor/ThirdParty/dex2jar\lib/dx.jar;Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/Thi
rdParty/dex2jar\lib/jar-rename-1.6.jar;Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/ThirdPart
y/dex2jar\lib/asmin-p2.5.jar -Xms1024m -Xms1024m com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.De
x2jarCmd -f -o "C:\Users\THREEG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vbqpzsn0.9r6.jar" "C:\Users
\THREEG~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jhcbrbrz.ocm./classes.dex"
```

I have checked the folder structure inside the project and dex2jar seems to be present. We did not see this issue before updating.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself. This is most likely due to a spelling error in AndroidApkCreator.cs, row 39, where "lib/asmin-p2.5.jar" instead should read "lib/jasmin-p2.5.jar", judging by the file name inside the lib folder. This does not seem to completely remove the issue, however, as the CMD prompt still throws the following Error:
Could not find or load main class com.googlecode.dex2jar.tools.Dex2JarCmd

Comment: This issue might have been resolved by updating the android SDK. If so, it might be helpful to indicate required version of the Android SDK in the documentation.